# Проблема с кодировкой в Android+java URLConnection

Tags: java, android, кодировка, utf-8

Столкнулся с ОЧЕНЬ странной проблемой, ответа на которую не нашел в гугле.

Есть задача - с помощью приложения Android скачать html страницу и далее с ней работать. Казалось бы все хорошо, но ссылка содержит русские символы, поэтому скачивается пустая html страница.

Эту русскую часть страницы я беру из EditText.
Ссылка формируется.
Скачивается пустая страница.

Прочитал про эту проблему, все пишут воспользоваться перекодировкой русской части в utf-8.
Перекодировал.
Скачалась пустая страница.

Чтобы самостоятельно проверить ссылку, поместил текст ссылки в этот EditText.
Копирую.
Перехожу по ней через браузер на смартфоне - ссылка открывается правильная!

Но вот с компьютера через браузер Chrome она опять открывается пустая.
Попробовал перекодировать не только русскую часть, а всю ссылку целиком - проблем осталась.

Перечитал все форумы, все пишут про utf-8, но это не работает, что делать?

Метод извлечения русской части

```
private String getGroup ()
{
    EditText textEdit = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.groupEditText);
    String group = textEdit.getText().toString();
    return group;
}
```

Метод, формирующий ссылку

```
private String getUrlString ()
{
    String firstURL = getString(R.string.url_first);
    String group = getGroup();
    try
    {
        URLEncoder.encode(group, "utf-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_error);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_group_message);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    String secondURL = getString(R.string.url_second);
    String finaURL = firstURL + group + secondURL;
    return finaURL;
}
```

На всякий случай метод соединения

```
URL url = new URL(timeTableURL);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

createDir(getString(R.string.directory));
String fileName = getString(R.string.directory) + "/TimeTable" + timeTableGroup + ".html";
File file = new File(fileName);

if (!file.exists())
{
    file.createNewFile();
}

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
while ((inputLine = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    bufWriter.write(inputLine);
}

bufWriter.close();
bufReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код ничего не делает

```
URLEncoder.encode(group, "utf-8");
```

должно быть

```
group = URLEncoder.encode(group, "utf-8");
```

Если `group` это GET параметр, то этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! В очередной раз убеждаюсь, что лучше сначала читать документацию :)

Comment: Здесь правило простое. В Java все строки immutable, т.е. неизменяемые. Обьект строки всегда пересоздается при попытке изменения его содержания. Поэтому все функции, совершающие манипуляции над строками, возвращают новый обьект как результат.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать конвертировать url в [IDN][1]

Вот приведу пару примеров.

```
    val s = "test string с кирилицей"
    Log.d("log", "s в IDN ${IDN.toASCII(s)}")
```

в логах:

```
s в IDN xn--test string  -83k6baatow7hsa6j
```

и с рандомным url в рф зоне

```
    val ss = "минобрнауки.рф"
    Log.d("log", "ss в IDN ${IDN.toASCII(ss)}")
```

в логах:

```
ss в IDN xn--80abucjiibhv9a.xn--p1ai
```

где http://xn--80abucjiibhv9a.xn--p1ai url соответственно.

Как оказалось если использовать Jsoup то все сильно проще. В отдельном потоке можно без проблем получить исходники старницы

```
Jsoup.connect("https://eisgateway.mephi.ru/TimeTable/timetableshow.aspx?gr=%D0%B003-23&prep=&typ=gr").get()
```

Comment: я только что попробовал конвертировать в IDN отдельно русскую часть, отдельно всю ссылку, но при конвертации всей ссылки URL connection отказывается с ней работать (приложение вылетает), а при конвертации русской части - ссылка опять не правильная. Как быть то ?

Comment: собственно вот интересующая ссылка, на всякий случай https://eisgateway.mephi.ru/TimeTable/timetableshow.aspx?gr=%D0%B003-23&prep=&typ=gr
где черт знает что начинается после "gr=...." и часть "%D0%B003-23" по идее это "а03-23"

Comment: Добавил как это можно сделать в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Надо энкодить строку вызова, примерно так:

```
url = UrlEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
```

Comment: UrlEncoder предназначен для кодирования только параметров запроса. Всю ссылку запроса им кодировать нельзя.

Comment: Согласен, фигню написал)